# How to get all the values for a given key of a dictionary in q lang(kdb+)

Tags: finance, kdb

Let's say we have a dictionary

```
ddup:`a`b`a`c!10 20 30 20
```

When I write command as `` ddup[`a] ``
output: 10
But how to put input to get
output: 10 30

```
(key ddup)[where (key ddup) = `a]
`a`a
ddup[(key ddup)[where (key ddup) = `a]]
10 10
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the result you're looking for by doing:

```
(value ddup) where `a = key ddup
```

The best option though is to not set up your dictionary like this in the first place. Keeping to a set of distinct keys would be far more efficient.
If possible I would consider restructuring the dictionary to be like:

```
q)dict:`a`b`c!(10 30;20;20)
q)dict
a| 10 30
b| 20
c| 20
```

Answer (score 1):

As Sean said, you should restructure your data rather than work around it. As mentioned in the documents, operations on dictionaries and tables with duplicate keys are undefined - this can cause you larger issues further down the line.

https://code.kx.com/q/basics/dictsandtables/#construction